# python, SQLite3 showing existing Tables and data

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have been given a .db file, that has already been populated with both Tables and Data. However, no description of the content of the database has been made available.

Is there a way for me to retrieve individual lists listing the different tables, and their respective sets of columns using SQLite3 and python?

Comment: The `.schema` command in the sqlite3 shell, or querying the `sqlite_master` table in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code help you to show tables with keys , when you get tables and their keys you can get data.

```
import sqlite3

def readDb():

    connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    tabs=[]
    for row in rows:
        for r in row:
            tabs.append(r)
    d={}
    for tab in tabs:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+tab+";")
        rows = cursor.fetchone()
        t=[] 
        for row in rows.keys():
            t.append(row)

        d[tab]=t
    connection.commit()
    return d


print(readDb())
```